# determine a and b so that the function is continuous

Tags: continuity

I have an assignment where I should determine $a$ and $b$ so that the following function is continuous at $x=0$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  2+\ln(1+x), & x>0\\
  x^2+ax+b, & x\le 0
\end{cases}$$

I can do that just by setting $x = 0$ and calculating $$ 2+\ln(1+x)=x^2+ax+b$$

The answer is that $b=2$ and $a$ could be anything. Here comes the second part of the assingment, which I do not understand:

Determine, by calculating left and right limit of the differential quotient, all the values on the real parameters $a$ and $b$ so that $f$ is differentiable at the point $x=0$.

How do I do that, and what is the differential quotient? And what do I google if I want to search for this kind of problems?

Comment: The fact that the function values are identical does not imply continuity. Just one piece more !!!

Comment: Does it not? What am I missing then?

Comment: I guess the equality of derivatives at $x=0$. Remember what implies continuity. Cheers.

Comment: Are you saying that the function has to be differentiable to be continious? I did not thaught that was a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You want to determine when $\displaystyle f^{\prime}(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ exists by evaluating the one-sided limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$
and $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ and seeing when these are equal.

Comment: And can I do that by doing this: $lim_{x\to0}\frac{d}{dx}(2+\ln(1+x))=lim_{x\to0}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+ax+b)$?

Comment: You want to use $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{2+\ln(1+h)-b}{h}$ when $h>0$, and $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{(h^2+ah+b)-b}{h}$ when $h<0$.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that I get the right answer with my calculation then?

Comment: @theva Your calculation will usually give the right answer.  You have to be careful, though: if $f(x)=x^2+1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x^3$ for $x\ge0$, you might be led by your method to conclude that $f^{\prime}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The differential quotient is most likely the difference quotient: $\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$.

The problem wants you to find $a$ and $b$ so that the function is differentiable at $x = 0$. In other words, you want find $a$ and $b$ so that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h}$.

As for what to google, try "piecewise differentiability".

Comment: I don't get it. How do I calculate x1, x2, y1 and y2 in the first place?

Comment: Ooops. You're right. What I wrote before didn't make any sense. I hope this makes more sense.